# How to get the null values from two tables WHERE user_id IS NULL is not working in Node.js MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to get NULL values from two tables by using  *** LEFT JOIN *** and i used

where clause conditions

```
WHERE L.user_id is null OR L.user_id=1
WHERE ( L.user_id is null OR L.user_id=1)
WHERE isnull(L.user_id) OR L.user_id=1
```

But all they above conditions are working fine in MYSQL, but not working fine in NODE.JS API

NODE.JS CODE

```
router.post('/get_All_Posts_like_Status/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Query', req.query, 'Body', req.body);
  var userId = req.body.params.userId;

  connection.query(" SELECT P.id, P.description, P.user_id, L.post_id, L.user_id AS likes_user_id, L.like_status,  \
   CASE   \
   WHEN L.user_id='" + userId + "' THEN '" + userId + "'   \
   when L.user_id is NULL THEN 0 \
   ELSE 'No_user' end AS id_user   \
   FROM posts AS P LEFT JOIN likes AS L ON L.post_id=P.id   \
   WHERE (L.user_id='" + userId + "' OR L.user_id IS NULL )  \
   ORDER BY created_date DESC ", (err, results, fields) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)))
      all_Posts_like_Status_Array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
      return res.json({ "status": 200, "error": null, "res_result": all_Posts_like_Status_Array });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      return res.json({ "status": 400, "error": err, "res_result": 'Sorry no data found for saved_Posts_Status or something wrong ' });
    }
  })
});
```

MYSQL CODE :

```
  SELECT P.id, P.description, P.user_id, L.post_id, L.user_id AS likes_user_id, L.like_status,  
   CASE   
   WHEN L.user_id=1 THEN 1   
   when L.user_id is NULL THEN 0 
   ELSE 'No_user' end AS id_user   
   FROM posts AS P LEFT JOIN likes AS L ON L.post_id=P.id   
   WHERE (L.user_id=1 OR L.user_id IS NULL )  
   ORDER BY created_date DESC
```

Please check the both MYSQL CODE and NODE.JS CODE

Mysql code is working fine in mysql RUN but when i use it in node.js its not working fine,
i am not getting null values i am getting user_id=1 values only

please tell me if anyone know the solutions to get the NULL values in node.js API